# not getting the appropriate email body content using imap nodejs, only for few mails

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, imap

**Hello,**

**I am using Imap nodejs module to get the content of the emails, but sometime for some mails, I am getting the wrong content of body. e.g. for one mail I am getting body content as below**

```
SGkgTmFkZWVtDQoNCiANCg0KT3VyIENFTyBpcyBjdXJyZW50bHkgdHJhdmVsbGluZyBhbmQgd291 bGQgbm90IGJlIGF2YWlsYWJsZSB0aGlzIHdlZWsuIFdlIGFyZSBwZW5kaW5nIGFwcHJvdmFsIG9m IHRoZSBjb250cmFjdCwgd291bGQgdXBkYXRlIEFTQVAuDQoNCiANCg0KLS0NCg0KVGhhbmtzICYg UmVnYXJkcywNCg0KIA0KDQpNYXlhbmsgSi4gR3VsYXRpDQoNCk1hbmFnZXIgfCBQcm9kdWN0cyB8 IEVudGVycHJpc2UgQnVzaW5lc3MgfCBBQ0wgTW9iaWxlIExpbWl0ZWQNCg0KTW9iaWxlLyBCb2Fy ZCBOdW1iZXI6ICs5MS4gODgwMC05OTg5LTIwDQoNCiANCg0KRnJvbTogTWF5YW5rIEp5b3RpIEd1 bGF0aSANClNlbnQ6IFRodXJzZGF5LCBOb3ZlbWJlciAyMCwgMjAxNCAxMjo1OSBQTQ0KVG86ICdO YWRlZW0gSXFiYWwnDQpDYzogJ1Nob2JoaXQgRWxoYW5jZSc7IFJpc2hpIFRhbmRvbg0KU3ViamVj dDogUkU6IEFwcGxhbmUgLSBGb2xsb3cgVXANCg0KIA0KDQpIaQ0KDQogDQoNCkFzIGRpc2N1c3Nl ZCwgdGhlIGNvbnRyYWN0IGlzIHVuZGVyIENFT+KAmXMgYXBwcm92YWwuIFdvdWxkIHVwZGF0ZSBB U0FQLg0KDQogDQoNCi0tDQoNClRoYW5rcyAmIFJlZ2FyZHMsDQoNCiANCg0KTWF5YW5rIEouIEd1 bGF0aQ0KDQpNYW5hZ2VyIHwgUHJvZHVjdHMgfCBFbnRlcnByaXNlIEJ1c2luZXNzIHwgQUNMIE1v YmlsZSBMaW1pdGVkDQoNCk1vYmlsZS8gQm9hcmQgTnVtYmVyOiArOTEuIDg4MDAtOTk4OS0yMA0K DQogDQoNCkZyb206IE5hZGVlbSBJcWJhbCBbbWFpbHRvOm5hZGVlbS5pcWJhbEBhcHBsYW5lLmNv bV0gDQpTZW50OiBXZWRuZXNkYXksIE5vdmVtYmVyIDE5LCAyMDE0IDU6MTYgUE0NClRvOiBSaXNo aSBUYW5kb247IE1heWFuayBKeW90aSBHdWxhdGkNCkNjOiAnU2hvYmhpdCBFbGhhbmNlJw0KU3Vi
```

**Now I have send this email to me, and then I have read body-content using my emailid, then I have got right body-content, which is like:**

> more details =C2=BB Booked for Applane
>   Team *When* Tue Dec 2, 2014 1pm =E2=80=93 3pm India Standard Time
>   *Video call* https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/daffodilsw.com/nadeem  *Calendar* Nadeem Iqbal *Who*
>   =E2=80=A2 Mandeep Singh - creator =E2=80=A2 Nadeem Iqbal Going?

**my code for getting email content is as follow:-**

```
       imap.once('ready', function () {
            imap.openBox("[Gmail]/All Mail", true, function (err, box) {
                if (err) {
                    d.reject(err);
                }
                var Moment = require("moment");
                var sDate = Moment(startDate).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
                var mailSearchOptions = [];
                if (params.mailSearchOptions) {
                    mailSearchOptions = params.mailSearchOptions
                } else {
                    mailSearchOptions.push(['SINCE', sDate]);
                    if (uid) {
                        mailSearchOptions.push(["uid", uid + ":*"])
                    }
                }
                try {
                    imap.search(mailSearchOptions, function (err, results) {
                        if (err) {
                            d.reject(err);
                            return
                        }
                        if (!results || (Array.isArray(results) && results.length == 0)) {
                            d.reject(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        var f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (TO FROM SUBJECT CC)', '1', '1.1'], struct: true });

                        f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {
                            console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
                            var mailDate = false;
                            var head = "";
                            var text = "";
                            var attechmentText = "";
                            msg.on("body", function (stream, info) {
                                stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
                                    if (info.which == 'HEADER.FIELDS (TO FROM SUBJECT CC)') {
                                        head += chunk.toString('utf8');
                                    }
                                    else if (info.which == "1") {
                                        text += chunk.toString('utf8');
                                    } else {
                                        attechmentText += chunk.toString('utf8');
                                    }
                                });
                                stream.once('end', function () {
                                    if (info.which == 'HEADER.FIELDS (TO FROM SUBJECT CC)') {
                                        head = require("imap").parseHeader(head);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            msg.once('attributes', function (attrs) {
                                lastUid = attrs.uid;
                                mailDate = attrs.date;
                            });
                            msg.once('end', function () {
                                if (!uid || (uid && lastUid !== parseInt(uid))) {
                                    var mailbody = "";
                                    if (attechmentText != "null") {
                                        mailbody = attechmentText;
                                    } else {
                                        mailbody = text;
                                    }
                                    formatEmails(head);
                                    head.subject = head.subject ? head.subject[0] : "";
                                    var participants = [];
                                    populateParticipants(head, username, participants);
                                    mails.push({head: head, body: mailbody, date: mailDate, participants: participants, user: {_id: userid, username: username}, uid: lastUid});
                                }

                            });
                        });
                        f.once('error', function (err) {
                            d.reject(err);
                        });
                        f.once('end', function () {
                            console.log('Done fetching all messages!!!!');
                            if (!params.maintainLogs) {
                                return  updateLastUid(lastUid, uid, userid, db).then(function () {
                                    imap.end();
                                });
                            } else {
                                imap.end();
                            }

                        });
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    d.reject(e);
                }
            });
        });

        imap.once('error', function (err) {
            console.log("Error>>>>" + err);
            d.reject(err);
        });

        imap.once('end', function () {
            console.log('Connection ended');
            d.resolve(mails);
        });

        imap.connect();
```

**Can someone inform me what I am doing wrong???**

**Thanks for help**

Comment: That email contains a header field saying "content-transfer-encoding: base64". The content is indeed encoded using base64. Most IMAP clients retrieve header information (including c-t-e) using envelope/bodystructure and then retrieve and decode the body using the c-t-e they now know.

Comment: what I have required to do, I have not got your point properly.

Comment: Thanks, by doing mailbody = new Buffer(mailbody, "base64"), I have got the desired result, but by doing this format of all other emails get changed, and are not readable, so how I can decide, in which cases I should do this?

Comment: You can decide when you need to do this by first checking the value of the Content-Transfer-Encoding header.

Comment: Thanks Elchonon Edelson,I have done that.